# Summation of $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$

Tags: summation, telescopic-series

I saw this problem initially and thought it would be pretty easy from some nice cancellation, but it just didn't happen:

$$\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{12} + \ldots + \frac{1}{8010}$$

This can be rewritten as:

$$\frac{1}{(1)(2)} + \frac{1}{(2)(3)} + \frac{1}{(3)(4)} + \ldots + \frac{1}{(89)(90)}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{89} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$

From here, I simply found a pattern by figuring out a few of the first partial sums;
they are $\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{4}{5}.$
So, the rule for the sum of the first *n* terms is probably just
$\frac{n}{n+1}$, meaning the answer is $\frac{89}{90}$.

However, I want to know how to solve this sum without just calculating the first few partial sums. Is there a formula for this type of series that I just don't know? Or is there a subtle trick I can do with the original sum of fractions, something like in a telescoping series? Thank you.

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate. Write $1/n(n+1) = 1/n - 1/(n+1)$ and see the telescoping sum.

Comment: $\frac 1{n(n+1)}=\frac 1n-\frac 1{n+1}$. That helps?

Comment: Oh wow, now I'm surprised that slipped my mind completely. Thanks, getting the answer is really easy from here on out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ in terms of $k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1950977/finding-sum-limits-n-1k-frac1nn1-in-terms-of-k) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7Bm%7D%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn(n%2B1)%7D%24&p=1).

Answer (score 1):

This is both a generalization
and a comment.

Since

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+m)}-\dfrac1{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+m+1)}\\
=\dfrac1{(n+1)...(n+m)}\left(\dfrac1{n}-\dfrac1{(n+m+1)}\right)\\
=\dfrac1{(n+1)...(n+m)}\left(\dfrac{m+1}{n(n+m+1)}\right)\\
=\dfrac{m+1}{n(n+1)...(n+m)(n+m+1)}\\
\end{array}
$

replacing $m+1$ by $m$

$\dfrac{m}{n(n+1)...(n+m)(n+m)}
=\dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+m-1)}-\dfrac1{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+m)}
$

so

$\dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+m)(n+m)}
=\dfrac1{m}\left(\dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+m-1)}-\dfrac1{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+m)}\right)
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=a}^b \dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+m)(n+m)}\\
=\sum_{n=a}^b\dfrac1{m}\left(\dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+m-1)}-\dfrac1{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+m)}\right)\\
=\dfrac1{m}\sum_{n=a}^b\left(\dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+m-1)}-\dfrac1{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+m)}\right)\\
=\dfrac1{m}\left(\sum_{n=a}^b\dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+m-1)}-\sum_{n=a}^b\dfrac1{(n+1)(n+2)...(n+m)}\right)\\
=\dfrac1{m}\left(\sum_{n=a}^b\dfrac1{n(n+1)...(n+m-1)}-\sum_{n=a+1}^{b+1}\dfrac1{n(n+1)(n+2)...(n+m-1)}\right)\\
=\dfrac1{m}\left(\dfrac1{a(a+1)...(a+m-1)}-\dfrac1{(b+1)(b+2)...(b+m)}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

Note that:
$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Therefore:
$$\sum_{n＝1}^{89}\frac {1}{n(n＋1)} ＝ \sum_{n＝1}^{89}\frac {1}{n}-\frac {1}{n＋1} ＝ 1-\frac {1}{89＋1} ＝ \frac{89}{90}.$$

Comment: Please do not answer questions that are duplicates.